# Joint Controller plugin not creating topic in ignition gazebo

Tags: control, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've made a simple robot with 3 joints and I've applied the joint state publisher, pose publisher and joint controller plugins.

The joint state publisher and pose publisher plugins create their topics and I can interface them with ros_ign_bridge without issues. However, the joint controller plugin isn't creating a topic for the joint I specified.

Here is the SDF:

[image: image description]

Here is the ignition GUI showing all topics:

[image: image description]

As shown in the last figure, there is no joint control topic for the 'joint_shoulder2base' joint.

Can some one help me with this issue? Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28615/joint-controller-plugin-not-creating-topic-in-ignition-gazebo/) by [vtr101](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/119262/vtr101/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The topics you see in that GUI are all topics being published by plugins or the core itself. Topics that are subscribed to are not listed there. You can look at the debug output on the console to find out what topic the joint controller has subscribed to.

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2022-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vtr101](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/119262/vtr101/) on 2022-12-07**:
Indeed the topics show up when i use the -v4 argument. Thank you